# Update child table foreign key values using datable.merge()

Tags: c#, dataset

When master table after update get new values for PrimaryKey column from database with:

```
ndaMasterAdapter.Update(dtChanges); 
dtMasterTable.Merge(dtChanges);
```

it does not update ForeignKey in slave table.

Update\Delete rules in dataset relation properties set to cascade:

```
.DeleteRule = global::System.Data.Rule.Cascade;
.UpdateRule = global::System.Data.Rule.Cascade;
```

Insert command (i use npgsql for postgresql):

```
ndaMasterAdapter.InsertCommand = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Test\".\"Master\" (master_text) values (:master_text) returning id, master_text;");
ndaMasterAdapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
ndaMasterAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
```